# Is it possible to use NewtonSoft.Json inside a T4 template?

Tags: c#, json.net, t4

I want to deserialize some JSON inside a T4 template. I've referenced the assembly and all that and it all looks good but when I call this:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
```

I get this:

```
Error   4   Running transformation: System.TypeLoadException: Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Data.Json.IJsonValue'. ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.JsonValueConverter.CanConvert(Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.GetMatchingConverter(IList`1 converters, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.InitializeContract(JsonContract contract)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating051377DF83FAD6CEB531E8C53BDF7AF0925D52AE4E0D72D32E8A27AD05041FA9D55204F2BCFCC44A6977B1EA4AD1DA5E9682BFE9EB924836019C6E14E1AED232.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetInfoForCountries() in c:\************\CalabashTestGeneration\Template1.tt:line 117
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating051377DF83FAD6CEB531E8C53BDF7AF0925D52AE4E0D72D32E8A27AD05041FA9D55204F2BCFCC44A6977B1EA4AD1DA5E9682BFE9EB924836019C6E14E1AED232.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() in c:\****************\CalabashTestGeneration\Template1.tt:line 24  c:\*************\CalabashTestGeneration\Template1.tt    117 1   CalabashTestGeneration
```

Is this even possible? I don't see why a T4 couldn't use newtonsoft but this kind of hints that it can't!

Comment: Can you show how you import your assembly in your template? I used NewtonSoft.Json in T4,it works but there's a few things to take care of.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I've ended up using restsharp - seems to work so far

Comment: This does not at all answer the question. This might be good to know as a comment on the OP, but it's not an answer and certainly shouldn't be the accepted answer.